# selectInput Selected is not displaying data from a dataframe (flexdashboard, shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, dt, flexdashboard

I'm using an inline Shiny app inside a flexdashboard and would like to display a datatable with a drop-down menu, with a specific year of data displaying automatically. The drop-down menu appears but it is not populated with the default year I have selected, 2022. As well, no datatable appears by default. If I use the drop-down menu I can select a year and then it does populate a datatable. Any help is appreciated!

The code is live at https://whheresourceusage.shinyapps.io/dash/#section-e-journals. I will replicate a code snippet here:

```html
title: "Electronic Resource Usage"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    css: my-custom-rules.css
    theme: bootstrap
    logo: primary.png
    favicon: fav.png
    orientation: rows 
    vertical_layout: scroll
    social: ["twitter", "menu"]
    source_code: embed 
    includes:
      in_header: GA_Script.html
runtime: shiny

Top10v <- read_excel("dashdata_FY22.xlsx", sheet = "Top10vid")

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
        selectInput(inputId = "Year", label = "Choose a year", choices = c(Top10v$Year), selected = "2022", multiple = FALSE),
      DT::DTOutput(outputId = "table3", height = "100%")
), 
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table3 <- DT::renderDT({
    filter(Top10v, Year == input$Year)
    }, options = list(height = "550px", scrollY = "550px", scrollCollapse = TRUE, dom = "t"))
  }
)
```

The "Top10vid" sheet of the dashdata_FY22.xlsx file in question looks like (10 entries for each year):
[screen shot of the data structure of dashdata_FY22.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxP8f.png)

Here is some sample code, using dput and copied from the console:

```html
> library(readxl)
> Top10v <- read_excel("/Users/...path.../dashdata_FY22.xlsx", sheet = "Top10vid")
> dput(Top10v)                                                                                                                                                                                   
structure(list(Year = c(2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020), Titles = c("The Inventor: Out for Blood in Silicon Valley", 
"Indecent", "Group Counseling, Process and Technique", "No", 
"Antigone", "Falsettos", "Ethnic Notions", "Persepolis", "The Gospel According to St. Matthew", 
"Dancing: The Individual and Tradition", "Brief Counseling: The Basic Skills", 
"Portrait of Jason", "Ethnic Notions", "Black Girl", "The Inventor: Out for Blood in Silicon Valley", 
"Dancing: The Individual and Tradition", "TEDTalks: Alicia Garza, Patrisse Cullors, and Opal Tometi: An Interview with the Founders of Black Lives Matter", 
"Winsor McCay: The Master Edition", "19th Century American Whaleman", 
"Killer of Sheep", "Brief Counseling: The Basic Skills", "Animal Kingdom", 
"Manga Ulysses", "Indecent", "Buried Child", "Falsettos", "Counseling Gay and Lesbian Youth", 
"Turbans", "Coming Home", "Any Day Now"), Publisher = c("Infobase", 
"BroadwayHD", "vcYES Productions", "Sony Pictures Classics", 
"Royal National Theatre", "BroadwayHD", "Infobase", "Sony Pictures Classics", 
"Infobase", "ArtHaus Musik", "Microtraining Associates", "Milestone Films", 
"Infobase", "Infobase", "Infobase", "ArtHaus Musik", "Infobase", 
"Milestone Films", "A&E Television Networks", "Milestone Films", 
"Microtraining Associates", "Sony Pictures Classics", "Contemporary Arts Media", 
"BroadwayHD", "BroadwayHD", "BroadwayHD", "Microtraining Associates", 
"Filmakers Library", "Sony Pictures Classics", "Music Box Films"
), Platform = c("Films On Demand", "Alexander Street Press", 
"Alexander Street Press", "Alexander Street Press", "Alexander Street Press", 
"Alexander Street Press", "Films On Demand", "Alexander Street Press", 
"Films On Demand", "Alexander Street Press", "Alexander Street Press", 
"Alexander Street Press", "Films On Demand", "Films On Demand", 
"Films On Demand", "Alexander Street Press", "Films On Demand", 
"Alexander Street Press", "Alexander Street Press", "Alexander Street Press", 
"Alexander Street Press", "Alexander Street Press", "Alexander Street Press", 
"Alexander Street Press", "Alexander Street Press", "Alexander Street Press", 
"Alexander Street Press", "Alexander Street Press", "Alexander Street Press", 
"Alexander Street Press"), `Number of items requested` = c(796, 
342, 253, 206, 188, 176, 167, 149, 140, 134, 356, 288, 271, 235, 
225, 181, 169, 166, 163, 153, 279, 153, 150, 147, 125, 120, 110, 
92, 80, 79)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Comment: Try `choices = unique(Top10v$Year)` in the `selectInput`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw this option early on in my troubleshooting and tried it out. Using unique() populates the drop-down menu with the options (that is an improvement from the blank drop-down menu without unique()) but it still doesn't generate the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(tidyverse)
choices <- unique(Top10v$Year)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "Year", label = "Choose a year", choices = choices, selected = choices[1], multiple = FALSE),
    DT::DTOutput(outputId = "table3", height = "100%")
  ), 
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    df <- reactive(Top10v %>%  filter(Year == input$Year) )
    output$table3 <- DT::renderDT({
      df()
    }, options = list(height = "550px", scrollY = "550px", scrollCollapse = TRUE, dom = "t"))
  }
)
```

Comment: I gave this a try and the 2022 datatable is still not populating by default, there's just a blank area until I select an option from the drop-down menu. I haven't tried introducing reactive components until now and will go do some reading on it. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you can post some sample data: use `dput(Top10v)` and put the output of that in your question.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the data, using dput and copying from the console. I hope this is useful for troubleshooting. Thanks again for your help so far.

Comment: Please try the updated answer.

Comment: Wow, yes, that updated answer solves the problem. I learned so much by troubleshooting alongside you. Thank you very much, @YBS!